# HIbernate translation of native Sql Query in Spring-data-jpa

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am building a springboot application with spring data jpa. I am using jpa repository with custom query.
When I run the query with `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`option enabled I am seeing a different query in the logs.
I have also tried running the query with just a union without the CTE. The query was still being misinterpreted with the `count(where)`
Can somebody help me understand what I am missing here?

```
final String CATEGORY_SEARCH_SQL_QUERY = """
             with cte as (
              select * from category
                          where 
                          is_user_specific=false
                          and 
                          category_lablel LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :categoryLabelQuery, '%'))
                          union
                          select *
                          from category
                          where is_user_specific=true
                          and created_by = :user
                          and category_lablel LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :categoryLabelQuery, '%')))
             select * from cte;
             """;

 @Query(value = CATEGORY_SEARCH_SQL_QUERY , nativeQuery = true)
     Page<CategoryEntity> searchforCategory(String categoryLabelQuery, String user, Pageable pageable);
```

logs

```
Hibernate: with cte as (
 select * from category
             where
             is_user_specific=false
             and
             category_lablel LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', ?, '%'))
             union
             select *
             from category
             where is_user_specific=true
             and created_by = ?
             and category_lablel LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', ?, '%')))
select * from cte fetch first ? rows only;

Hibernate: with cte as (select count(where) from category
             where
             is_user_specific=false
             and
             category_lablel LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', ?, '%'))
             union
             select *
             from category
             where is_user_specific=true
             and created_by = ?
             and category_lablel LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', ?, '%')))
select * from cte;

2024-01-31T21:02:37.099+01:00  WARN 31263 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2024-01-31T21:02:37.099+01:00 ERROR 31263 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "where"
  Position: 27
2024-01-31T21:02:37.106+01:00 ERROR 31263 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [with cte as (select count(where) from category
             where
             is_user_specific=false
             and
             category_lablel LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', ?, '%'))
             union
             select *
             from category
             where is_user_specific=true
             and created_by = ?
             and category_lablel LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', ?, '%')))
select * from cte;
] [ERROR: syntax error at or near "where"
  Position: 27] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "where"
  Position: 27
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2401) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:368) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:498) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:415) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:134) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]
```

Comment: Not really a solution, but I have the impression the problem is due to use `Pageable`, which issues a query to count the total number of rows. The query looks like fails due to this bit of the statement `count(where)`. I've experienced far too many issues with sping-jpa, and found that usually it's better to avoid it and use hibernate (or maybe sql in this case) directly.

Comment: @Augusto, thank you that seems to be the problem. I hope there is a solution for this.

Comment: Just one more notice: we should not use ```spring.jpa.show-sql``` property, there are better alternatives for this. For more details, please check https://vladmihalcea.com/log-sql-spring-boot/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `countQuery` to enter the correct count sql.

```java
@Query(
    value = CATEGORY_SEARCH_SQL_QUERY, 
    countQuery= COUNT_SQL, 
    nativeQuery = true
)
Page<CategoryEntity> searchforCategory(
    String categoryLabelQuery, 
    String user, 
    Pageable pageable
);
```

For example, you can start by optimizing `CATEGORY_SEARCH_SQL_QUERY`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM category
WHERE 
    (is_user_specific = false AND category_lablel LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :categorylabelquery, '%')))
    OR
    (is_user_specific = true AND created_by = :user AND category_lablel LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :categorylabelquery, '%')));
```

Then write the `COUNT_SQL`:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM category
WHERE 
    (is_user_specific = false AND category_lablel LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :categorylabelquery, '%')))
    OR
    (is_user_specific = true AND created_by = :user AND category_lablel LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :categorylabelquery, '%')));
```

Comment: I am not using a count sql... Do I need to have one?

Comment: @George Jose You will of course need to write your own counting sql that corresponds to `CATEGORY_SEARCH_SQL_QUERY `.

Comment: I don't need a count in this query I am using a pageable to look up based on the query. The count part is being generated by hibernate. The exact query to be run is written as the CTE.

Comment: However, in order to return a `Page`, it must be counted. 
And `Hibernate` is not infallible, it doesn't always generate the counting sql correctly based on the query sql. 
The error you are seeing is also due to the fact that it generates the wrong counting sql, which cannot be executed. 
That's why `@Query` has `countQuery`. 
So you can either optimize your query sql so that `Hibernate` generates the count sql correctly, or you can write your own count sql.